# How to update to the latest CakePHP 3.3.3 and bug fixes through composer

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.3

Recently I have reported a bugfix for Cakephp and the team has fixed the bug and merged it back to the cakephp repo (version 3.3.3). I wonder how to get the version of CakePhp.

In my application folder I run `composer update` and this is what is set into my composer.json file:

```
"require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "cakephp/cakephp": "~3.3",
        "mobiledetect/mobiledetectlib": "2.*",
        "cakephp/migrations": "~1.0",
        "cakephp/plugin-installer": "*",
        "dereuromark/cakephp-ajax": "dev-master"
    },
```

I can see in composer that the available versions are 3.3.1 and below. But is there any way that I can get those bug fixes from repo. Or is it fine if I downoad the file and upload it to my src/cake application folder.

Any help please

Comment: in my 3.3.3 application I see `"cakephp/cakephp": "~3.3"` In this way it is always updated to the latest version in the 3.3 branch

Comment: Thank you. It should be and composer update runs correctly with no error but the cake core files doesn't get updated. I'm going to check if it's about file permissions.

Comment: It is not file permissions as well.

Comment: when you run update you see something like 'removing 3.3.1, downloading 3.3.3'? Also, what version do you see now in `vendor/cakephp/cakephp/version.txt`?

Comment: Good point. it is 3.3.2

Comment: actually the latest version is 3.3.2, not 3.3.3 (I made a typo in my first comment). So maybe your bugs are not been solved in 3.3.2. What you want to do is download the master branch so to be up to date with the latest bufixes. Are you sure you can't wait till 3.3.3?

Comment: I have to get the bug fix from version 3.3.3. That's fine mate. Thank you for your help any way

Comment: https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/releases

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have composer installed globally, you can update the CakePHP to the latest version by running the following in terminal when in the project folder, the same directory composer.json lives in:

```
composer update
```

If you are having trouble with updating it can sometimes be caused by composer being out of date, update it regularly with the following in terminal:

```
composer self-update
```

Answer (score 2):

3.3.3 have not been releaset at this time so I guess you want to be up to date with the latest bugfixes that have not been released to a stable version

If you can't wait till 3.3.3 then the [**manual**](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/installation.html#keeping-up-to-date-with-the-latest-cakephp-changes) explains how to keep up to date with the latest changes. Just put in your composer.json:

```
"require": {
    "cakephp/cakephp": "dev-master"
}
```

and run `composer update`

> Be aware that is not recommended, as your application can break when the next major version is being released. Additionally composer does not cache development branches, so it slows down consecutive composer installs/updates.

Comment: I have tried this before but it retrieves lots of conflects

Comment: Cant you simply domngrade to 3.2 in the meanwhile?

Comment: No the available versions are 3.2.1 and below